# Make Xcode headers group

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake

I am generating Xcode project with CMake. In Xcode it compiles, executes, and debugs fine. But it shows only the cpp files in the `Source Files` group. Is there any way to add another `Header Files` group ? My project is compiling fine on Linux, and in Linux I am using KDevelop, there everything works just fine, and I don't want to break that. I don't want to put headers in `ADD_EXECUTABLE`.

Is there any macro in CMake that creates such files group only for a specific IDE ? Then I would create a group for headers, another group for ui files, another groups for resources etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily differentiate between project types in CMake. However, you must include the headers in the `add_executable` statement for them to be present in the project. I'm not really sure why you wouldn't want to add the headers in the `add_executable` statement, it shouldn't have any effect on compilation (the whole point of CMake is to be operational across multiple compilers!). However, you could easily do:

```
 if (defined XCODE_VERSION)
     add_executable(<ExeName> ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS});
 else()
     add_executable(<ExeName> ${SOURCES});
 endif()
```

Thus only affecting XCode projects. If you want to arrange the sources (headers, etc), in different groups within the IDE, the generic CMake command for doing that is [`source_group`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html). So, you could do:

```
 source_group("Source Files" FILES ${SOURCES});
 source_group("Header Files" FILES ${HEADERS});
```

Comment: I am getting error "defined" "XCODE_VERSION" Unknown arguments specified

Comment: Thanks `IF (DEFINED XCODE_VERSION)`worked. However how can I group the UI files ?

Comment: IMO, I would always add the headers instead of conditionally doing it only for Xcode.  You want the headers in other IDEs as well (VS, CLion, etc.).  Also, I don't know why you're writing CMake commands with `;` at the end.  This isn't CMake syntax; the command ends with the closing parenthesis.